# Remove space from a specific column in a Directory

Tags: excel, windows, vba, csv, batch-file

I have a lot of .csv files in a directory. The fourth column (Number) has spaces in between as in the example below. How can I remove space from the column only and apply the same to all the files within the directory without having to open each file one by one.

```
"EMIS Number","Organisation Name","Organisation Code","Number","Date","Clinical Code","Code Term",
"11","West Hampstead Medical Centre","F03033","931 094 3111","19-Apr-1019","G340-1","Coronary artery disease",
"14","Prince Of Wales Medical Centre","F03010","401 300 1319","03-Jan-1004","G30","Acute myocardial infarction",
"13","HAMPSTEAD GROUP PRACTICE","F03014","411 419 3949","1999","G3","Ischaemic heart disease",
"19","BROOKFIELD PARK SURGERY","F03031","400 134 0101","1991","G3","Ischaemic heart disease",
```

P.S. I have tried Excel and VBA but they both require opening each file to run a formula. I have also tried UltraEdit but it will remove all the spaces in all the files not one specific column.

Comment: So write a vba that loops through the files, opens each one and does the removal, then saves the file.

Comment: What is the problem with opening the file?

Comment: This is how far I got with the vba. I couldn't do the loop. Sorry I don't really know vba.

Sub SpaceKiller()
   Worksheets("CHD001").Columns("D").Replace _
      What:=" ", _
      Replacement:="", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
End Sub

Comment: Look into [Dir()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Its a lot of files and It's going to be a continuous process. It would be such a manual process to open each file every single time.

Comment: No it isn't.  You can do that in VBA, but I see you have been shown that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below code to loop through all files.

```
Sub OpenFiles()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    MyFolder = "Your Folder Name where all files are saved."
    Dim MyFile As String
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.csv")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
        Columns("D:D").Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Activeworkbook.close true
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Once you open your file add code to remove you space .

Comment: have made a little change in my code . `Activeworkbook.close true`. thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: Oh Wow. It works perfectly. Thank you so much. You are a life saver.

Comment: This code was implemented into a process that was working perfectly well for a while and all of a sudden, when I run it now, all the files in the folder are coming with a prompt to save them in a location. I didn't change anything before this started and I have tried to fix this and exhausted everything I know. Would you know why this could have happened? Thanks!

Comment: Hi . use `Application.DisplayAlerts =False` just before `Activeworkbook.close true` and again `Application.DisplayAlerts =True` Please test it first before you apply on your actual files.

Comment: Great. I'll apply these changes. Thanks.